# Merging two files in unix, with one common column that is redundant

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have two files with one common column that is redundant.File 1 has chromosomal locations and TF's, file 2 has chromosomal locations and Refseq numbers.

File 1:

chr1:66997824-67000456      ZNF333 
chr1:66997824-67000456      EGR1
chr1:66997824-67000456      MZF-1
chr22:51221989-51222166      Zic2
   chr22:51221989-51222166      ZF5

File 2: 
chr1:66997824-67000456      Refseq#1
chr22:51221989-51222166      Refseq#22

I would like to merge these two files, and create a new file with three columns, 
chr1:66997824-67000456     ZNF333      Refseq#1 
chr1:66997824-67000456      EGR1      Refseq#1
chr1:66997824-67000456      MZF-1      Refseq#1
chr22:51221989-51222166      Zic2      Refseq#22
chr22:51221989-51222166      ZF5      Refseq#22

Since the chromosomal locations are redundant, I could not merge them using join in Unix - Is there a way to merge using sed or awk?

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: Try join command.

Answer (score 1):

```
join file1 file2
```

Output:

```
chr1:66997824-67000456 ZNF333 Refseq#1
chr1:66997824-67000456 EGR1 Refseq#1
chr1:66997824-67000456 MZF-1 Refseq#1
chr22:51221989-51222166 Zic2 Refseq#22
chr22:51221989-51222166 ZF5 Refseq#22
```

or

```
join file1 file2 | awk '{OFS="     ";print $1,$2,$3}'
```

Output:

```
chr1:66997824-67000456     ZNF333     Refseq#1
chr1:66997824-67000456     EGR1     Refseq#1
chr1:66997824-67000456     MZF-1     Refseq#1
chr22:51221989-51222166     Zic2     Refseq#22
chr22:51221989-51222166     ZF5     Refseq#22
```

Comment: It didn't work, it exited after printing the first refseq#. My first file has 2000+records with chromosomal locations chr1:66997824-67000456 - the join command printed Refseq#1 for those 2000+ records and then exited. My input file has almost 20000+ lines whereas the output has only 2000+ lines.

Comment: @ABB: It should work though, only IF THE FILES ARE SORTED though. Use `sort` if they are not. Else, are you sure there is no mismatch between the first field of the two files? To test, try first with a subset, e.g using `uniq -w 24` on file 1 and try to track your bug.

Comment: @ABB: Try this: `join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`